# Getting ID of all elements of a certain class into an array

Tags: jquery

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Currently I am using this to create an array of all elements matching the class name of `.cookie`. Right now I am getting the text value of that element, which is not what I need:

```
var getAllCookies = $('.cookie').text();
var cookiesArray = jQuery.makeArray(getAllCookies);
alert(cookiesArray[0]);
```

What I need is to find all elements of a certain class (.cookie), get that element's ID value and store that ID value inside of array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this should do what you're after:

```
var ids = $('.cookie').map(function(index) {
    // this callback function will be called once for each matching element
    return this.id; 
});
```

[Documentation for `map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

[Here's a working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwv55/).

Comment: `$.map` allows you to take one array or object and transform it into another. It takes what you return from it's callback and sticks it in an array and returns that new array.

Comment: So is the `.map()` automatically creating an array of elements with the class of `.cookie`?

Comment: and is `ids` my new array of element values? Can you tell me what `index` is doing exactly?

Comment: `$('.cookie')` gets you an array of elements that match the `'.cookie'` selector.  `map` takes a callback function that transforms each matched element into something else, in this case, the element's `id` value.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
var cookiesArray = [];

$('.cookie').each( function(i,e) {
    /* you can use e.id instead of $(e).attr('id') */
    cookiesArray.push($(e).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: or `.push(this.id)` or `.push(e.id)`

Comment: Is there any way you can explain what `function(i,e)` is doing? I also want to learn how to do this instead of just applying it.

Comment: Sure, `each()` iterates over the elements matched on the selector, `function` executes the code inside the brackets, `i` is the current index of the element (0,1,2,etc), and `e` is the current element, basically `$(e)` would be equivalent to `$(this)` during each iteration...

Comment: Oh okay I think I am following. Thank you. Let me try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cookiesArray = new Array();
$('.cookie').each(function() { 
  var id = $(this).attr(id);
  if(id != undefined) {
    cookiesArray.push(id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this one because it includes the 'if` statement, but I think it is too lengthy in all.

Comment: there you go -- maybe it's lengthy, but arguably also quite readable