# Getting ID of all elements of a certain class into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425661/getting-id-of-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-into-an-array), and the accepted answer provided:

```
var ids = $('.cookie').map(function(index) {
    // this callback function will be called once for each matching element
    return this.id; 
});
```

How can the above be done in pure javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
// using Function.prototype.call() to apply 
// Array.prototype.map() to the array-like NodeList returned
// by document.querySelectorAll():
var elementIDs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.cookie'), function (cookie) {
  // the first argument to the anonymous function ('cookie') is
  // the array element of the array over which we're iterating,
  // and is here a DOM node.

  // here, we return the id property of the current node:
  return cookie.id;
});
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).