# how to get data from tag of html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML snippet here:

```
<tr class="newRow">
  <td class="doc" ids="1">ABC</td>
  <td class="doc" ids="2">EFG</td>
  <td class="doc" ids="1">ABC</td>
  <td class="doc" ids="3">HIJ</td>
</tr>
```

And here is my script:

```
var formDoc = $.map($('.doc'), function(e) {
    return e.attr("ids");
});
alert(formDoc);
```

It only returns empty. Could you give me an advise to solve my issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting ID of all elements of a certain class into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425661/getting-id-of-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-into-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
return e.attr("ids");
```

to

```
return e.getAttribute("ids");
```

Comment: your answer is worked. but want you more help me to explain, this case why I can not used `attr()` , why must `getAttribute()` ?

Comment: @Songs, e is not jQuery object, it was rather DOM element, so it doesn't have jQuery methods, i guess.. you have to use native js functions.

Comment: `var elem = [];
    var formDoc = $.map($('.doc'), function(e) {
 elem.push(e);
    });`
try running this code, and see what you get in the 'elem' array. Its a normal html tag. attr is a jQuery method, which will only work on elements retrieved using jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 1):

`e` is an element from your `nodeList` and doesn't have jquery `attr` method which works on elements retrieved using jQuery selectors. So, you have to use `$(e).attr("ids")`.

```js
var formDoc=$.map($('td'),function(e) {
     return $(e).attr('ids');
});
console.log(formDoc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="newRow">
  <td class="doc" ids="1">ABC</td>
  <td class="doc" ids="2">EFG</td>
  <td class="doc" ids="1">ABC</td>
  <td class="doc" ids="3">HIJ</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out working code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr class="newRow">
      <td class="doc" ids="1">ABC</td>
      <td class="doc" ids="2">EFG</td>
      <td class="doc" ids="1">ABC</td>
      <td class="doc" ids="3">HIJ</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
     var formDoc = $.map($('.doc'), function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('ids');
        });
        alert(formDoc);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```